# Is there a range of launch velocities that would get my satellite as close to Mars as possible?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray, physics, orbital-mechanics

**Introduction**

Hi, I am trying to send a satellite which has a mass of 1062kg from Earth to Mars. My aim is to get it as close as possible to Mars but not orbit it. I am looking for a range of possible launch velocities for an Hohmann transfer orbit to Mars. For the snippets of relevant parts of my code I provide, you can assume that that my simulation of the solar system is working perfectly. The numerical algorithm that I am using is the Beeman with a timestep of 31577s.

```
def main():
    

    # get the velocity range
    velocity_range = np.linspace(0, 5000, 20)  # Example range of additional velocities
    min_distances = []
    velocities = []
    # run the simulation for additional velocities
    for additional_velocity in velocity_range:

        velocity_at_launch = sim_beeman.run(additional_velocity)
      
        
        velocities.append(velocity_at_launch)
        min_distance = sim_beeman.calculate_min_distance()
        min_distances.append(min_distance)


    print("velocities: ", velocities)

     
    # plot the velocity range vs minimum distance
    plt.plot(velocities, min_distances)
    plt.xlabel("satellite velocity at launch(m/s)")
    plt.ylabel("Minimum Distance (km)")
    plt.title("Minimum Distance vs satellite velocity at launch")
    plt.show()

def hohmann_transfer_parameters(G, mass_sun, radius_earth, radius_mars):
   

    # Semi-major axis of the transfer orbit
    a_transfer = (radius_earth + radius_mars) / 2  
    V_earth = np.sqrt(G * mass_sun / radius_earth)  # Earth's orbital velocity
    V_mars = np.sqrt(G * mass_sun / radius_mars)  # Mars' orbital velocity

    V_transfer_perihelion = np.sqrt(G * mass_sun * (2 / radius_earth - 1 / a_transfer))
    V_transfer_aphelion = np.sqrt(G * mass_sun * (2 / radius_mars - 1 / a_transfer))

    Delta_V1 = V_transfer_perihelion - V_earth  # ΔV to enter the transfer orbit


    return Delta_V1
```

The above equations are what I found to calculate the first burn velocity. Ignore the calculations for aphelion. The Hohmann function is not part of a class and all of the functions below are class functions.

```
 # function to run the simulation
def run(self, additional_velocity):
    # initialize simulation data for each run
    self.initialize_simulation_data()
    velocity_at_launch = 0
    self.satellite_launched = False
   
    # iterate over the number of iterations
    for i in range(self.iteration_counts):
        
        # update the position and velocity of each body in each iteration
        self.update_position()
        self.update_velocity()
    
        # Calculate Earth-Sun distance in the current iteration
        earth_distance_to_sun = np.linalg.norm(self.positions['earth'][-1])
        # get mars distance to sun
        mars_distance_to_sun = np.linalg.norm(self.positions['mars'][-1])

        # get the distance between earth and mars
        earth_to_mars_distance = np.linalg.norm(self.positions['earth'][-1] - self.positions['mars'][-1])
        #print("Current distance to sun: ", current_distance_to_sun)


        # check if the angle between the sun-earth and sun-mars vectors is about 44.3 degrees for launch
        if self.is_launch_time(earth_distance_to_sun, mars_distance_to_sun, earth_to_mars_distance ) and not self.satellite_launched: 
            # launch the satellite
            velocity_at_launch = self.launch_satellite(1.989e30, 147.1e9, 227.9e9, additional_velocity)
            self.satellite_launched = True
        


       
    return velocity_at_launch

def launch_satellite(self, mass_sun, radius_earth, radius_mars, additional_velocity):            
        print("Attempting to launch satellite near perihelion...")
        # Calculate Hohmann transfer parameters
        Delta_V1 = hohmann_transfer_parameters(self.G, mass_sun, radius_earth, radius_mars)
        print("Delta V1: ", Delta_V1)
        
        # get the earth's velocity vector at launch timestep
        earth_velocity = self.velocities["earth"][-1]  
        # get the earth's position vector at launch timestep
        earth_position = self.positions["earth"][-1]  # Earth's position vector
       

        # Calculate the unit vector in the direction of Earth's velocity
        earth_velocity_unit_vector = earth_velocity / np.linalg.norm(earth_velocity)
        earth_position_unit_vector = earth_position / np.linalg.norm(earth_position)

        # Calculate the satellite's velocity by applying ΔV in the direction of Earth's velocity
        satellite_velocity = earth_velocity + (Delta_V1 + additional_velocity) * earth_velocity_unit_vector + 1000

        # Calculate the satellite's position; placing it 200 km above Earth's surface
    
        satellite_position = earth_position + np.array([0, 6371e3 + 200e3])*earth_position_unit_vector

        # print parameters for launch
        print("Satellite velocity vector at launch:", satellite_velocity)
        print("Satellite position vector at launch:", satellite_position)
        
        print("satellite velocity at launch: ", np.linalg.norm(satellite_velocity))
        print("satellite position at launch : ", np.linalg.norm(satellite_position))

        print("Earth velocity vector at launch: ", earth_velocity)
        print("Earth position vector at launch: ", earth_position)

        print("Earth velocity magnitude at launch: ", np.linalg.norm(earth_velocity))
        print("Earth position magnitude at launch: ", np.linalg.norm(earth_position))

        print("\n\n")

        # Update satellite data
        self.velocities["satellite"].append(satellite_velocity)
        self.positions["satellite"].append(satellite_position)
        self.accelerations["satellite"].append(np.zeros(2))


       
        return np.linalg.norm(satellite_velocity)

        
          
def is_launch_time(self, sun_to_earth_distance, sun_to_mars_distance, Earth_to_mars_distance):
   # use the cosine rule to calculate the angle between the sun-earth and sun-mars vectors 
    angle_rads = math.acos((sun_to_earth_distance**2 + sun_to_mars_distance**2 - Earth_to_mars_distance**2) / (2 * sun_to_earth_distance * sun_to_mars_distance))
    angle_deg = np.degrees(angle_rads)
   
    # if the angle is between 44 and 46 degrees return true
    if 44 <= angle_deg <= 46:
        return True
    return False
```

Here are what my data structures for storing positions look like:

```
 {'sun': [array([0., 0.])], 'mercury': [array([5.78952e+10, 0.00000e+00])], 'venus': [array([1.081608e+11, 0.000000e+00])], 'earth': [array([1.496e+11, 0.000e+00])], 'mars': [array([2.279904e+11, 0.000000e+00])], 'jupiter': [array([7.7792e+11, 0.0000e+00])], 'saturn': [array([1.4212e+12, 0.0000e+00])], 'uranus': [array([2.87232e+12, 0.00000e+00])], 'neptune': [array([4.50296e+12, 0.00000e+00])], 'satellite': [array([0., 0.])]}
```

Above is the initial state of self.positions, where everything is in SI units. Velocities are also stored exactly the same way.

**Problem**

I read on the internet that the best time to launch a satellite for a hohmann transfer orbit is when the angle between earth and mars is about 44.3 degrees with sun as the origin. This is what I used to decide the timing of my launch. Since my aim was to discover the range of velocities, I ran the simulation multiple times and printed out the launch parameters in SI units, here are some of them:

```
Attempting to launch satellite near perihelion...
Delta V1:  3078.5906999237886
Satellite velocity vector at launch: [-31805.41409535  -1371.22945039]
Satellite position vector at launch: [-1.07767306e+10  1.49062981e+11]
satellite velocity at launch:  31834.95933690441
satellite position at launch :  149452033556.3857
Earth velocity vector at launch:  [-29734.83427786  -2149.2828756 ]
Earth position vector at launch:  [-1.07767306e+10  1.49056427e+11]
Earth velocity magnitude at launch:  29812.409939671335
Earth position magnitude at launch:  149445496725.23538



Attempting to launch satellite near perihelion...
Delta V1:  3078.5906999237886
Satellite velocity vector at launch: [-32067.88721996  -1390.20144085]
Satellite position vector at launch: [-1.07767306e+10  1.49062981e+11]
satellite velocity at launch:  32098.006959903447
satellite position at launch :  149452033556.3857
Earth velocity vector at launch:  [-29734.83427786  -2149.2828756 ]
Earth position vector at launch:  [-1.07767306e+10  1.49056427e+11]
Earth velocity magnitude at launch:  29812.409939671335
Earth position magnitude at launch:  149445496725.23538



Attempting to launch satellite near perihelion...
Delta V1:  3078.5906999237886
Satellite velocity vector at launch: [-32330.36034456  -1409.1734313 ]
Satellite position vector at launch: [-1.07767306e+10  1.49062981e+11]
satellite velocity at launch:  32361.05637597122
satellite position at launch :  149452033556.3857
Earth velocity vector at launch:  [-29734.83427786  -2149.2828756 ]
Earth position vector at launch:  [-1.07767306e+10  1.49056427e+11]
Earth velocity magnitude at launch:  29812.409939671335
Earth position magnitude at launch:  149445496725.23538



Attempting to launch satellite near perihelion...
Delta V1:  3078.5906999237886
Satellite velocity vector at launch: [-32592.83346917  -1428.14542175]
Satellite position vector at launch: [-1.07767306e+10  1.49062981e+11]
satellite velocity at launch:  32624.10754173499
satellite position at launch :  149452033556.3857
Earth velocity vector at launch:  [-29734.83427786  -2149.2828756 ]
Earth position vector at launch:  [-1.07767306e+10  1.49056427e+11]
Earth velocity magnitude at launch:  29812.409939671335
Earth position magnitude at launch:  149445496725.23538



Attempting to launch satellite near perihelion...
Delta V1:  3078.5906999237886
Satellite velocity vector at launch: [-32855.30659378  -1447.1174122 ]
Satellite position vector at launch: [-1.07767306e+10  1.49062981e+11]
satellite velocity at launch:  32887.160415209415
satellite position at launch :  149452033556.3857
Earth velocity vector at launch:  [-29734.83427786  -2149.2828756 ]
Earth position vector at launch:  [-1.07767306e+10  1.49056427e+11]
Earth velocity magnitude at launch:  29812.409939671335
Earth position magnitude at launch:  149445496725.23538



Attempting to launch satellite near perihelion...
Delta V1:  3078.5906999237886
Satellite velocity vector at launch: [-33117.77971838  -1466.08940266]
Satellite position vector at launch: [-1.07767306e+10  1.49062981e+11]
satellite velocity at launch:  33150.21495574151
satellite position at launch :  149452033556.3857
Earth velocity vector at launch:  [-29734.83427786  -2149.2828756 ]
Earth position vector at launch:  [-1.07767306e+10  1.49056427e+11]
Earth velocity magnitude at launch:  29812.409939671335
Earth position magnitude at launch:  149445496725.23538
```

Finally, I made a plot of Min distance from mars vs launch velocities that looks like:[image]

The lowest value y value of the graph is about 10^6 km at about 37580m/s. However, the radius of Mars is nearly 3785 km this suggests that I could get even closer to Mars, about 600 km above the surface of Mars. I don't know what I am missing about calculating the correct parameters or time of launch. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: This is absolutely beautiful! Good work! However, there are many things that you should consider in your simulation to improve it. If you want, I can later post it as an answer, but I would have to spend some time writting it down. 1) The velocities you're experimenting with seem to be a combination of Earth's orbital velocity, the ΔV for the transfer orbit, and additional velocities. Ensure that this range is realistic for achieving a flyby rather than entering orbit. You might need to adjust this range based on the specifics of your simulation.

Comment: 2) The optimal launch window depends on both planets' positions and velocities. Your current method for determining the launch window seems sound, but slight variations in timing could significantly affect the closest approach distance

Comment: 3) Beeman's algorithm is well-suited for integrating the equations of motion in many-body problems. However, ensure that your timestep is small enough to accurately capture the dynamics of the satellite as it approaches Mars

Comment: I'm not sure that Beeman's is quite up to it. RK4 or perhaps easier [Numerov's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerov%27s_method) was specifically developed for computing transfer orbits (on inferior Russian computers). It is still a good choice even today and not all that much more complex but O(4) in timestep. Worth a try with a higher order algorithm and some timestep control when near either end of the trip. Try stepping the initial velocity by tiny increments to see if the behaviour of trajectories is continuous or chaotic due to rounding.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes My timestep is 31577s. Additional velocities are to vary the calculated delta V. The ones on the plot are the magnitudes of the launch velocity vector. I tried to see the animation with the lowest point on the plot. The satellite first crosses mars and then gets close to mars. This is totally unintended and not fuel efficient. Around the 33000m/s the satellite gets as close as possible(10^7km) to mars on its first try. Answer to this question would be appreciated!

Comment: @MartinBrown I am not allowed to use any other simulation method by my school. I have met the aim of the problem by bringing the satellite within 10^6km of Mars. Therefore, I was wondering If i could get even closer.

Comment: OK. The zone near 35800 looks promising - you might want to zoom in on that a bit to see if any others get even closer. Making your code a function that returns distance of closest approach and then allowing an optimising code to look for the best combination of parameters might get you something better. Always worth halving and doubling the time step to see if that helps or hinders. If you have a series like that you can use [Richardson extrapolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson_extrapolation) to get a probably slightly better answer to a hard problem (unless you are unlucky).

Comment: If your university library has it you might want to take a look at Battin's book "An Introduction to the Mathematics and Methods of Astrodynamics" 1999, AIAA Education series if you are interested in more detail. Chapter 11 deals with transfer orbits (it isn't light reading) - still pretty much the reference for this stuff even now. You could always suggest to your school that Numerov/Cowell might be superior for the integration of the trajectory.